# How make JQuery intellisense work in aspx file?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I know how to make the intellisense work in a .js file using this `"/// <reference path="jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js`" />" but how to make it work in an aspx file.

I writing some jquery code in the page html itself and want to make the intellisense  work there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should work as long as you have the script reference in you aspx page, and VS can find that file in the path you specify.

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That said, best practice would be to avoid putting javascript in the page itself.  Create a separate .js file to contain all of your javascript.

Comment: but seams the 2 files must have the same name "jquery-1.3.2.js" and "jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js" to work

Comment: yes, that is true.  the vsdoc feature seems a bit hacky to me.  All VS does is look for a file with the same name as your .js file, but with -vsdoc at the end of the filename (before the .js).  This means you can create your own vsdoc files for your own intellisense.